# Creating MongoDB Collections based on Ids Dynamically

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data

We are using Spring Boot application with MongoDB. 
we are dealing with huge data (data will come each 30 min for the 100 devices) so Mongo is taking more time to insert and get the data from the MongoDB. So we decided to put each device data into a separate collection.

can anyone suggest us the right solution for this ? 
How to create/fetch from collections dynamically using JAVA and MongoDB ?

Comment: I think the following post has useful information related to the issue you are specifying: [Building with Patterns: The Bucket Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-bucket-pattern).

Comment: did you tried using insertMany or just using save in for loop?

Comment: yes we are using saveAll. not in the loop

Comment: @GajaMounikaGaja : So if you wanted to do it using multiple collection then your configuration check do go up (You need to check & send data to particular collection for a particular device) !! So this data-design is really dependent on your needs, you're writing avg of 5k docs a day & 150K a month, 1.8Million an year which is not too bad !! If you don't want to retain old data you can use capped collection which drops old docs, Also you need to properly maintain indexes (Less in number & efficient in a way), Also from application you can queue those data & write in one call to DB for an hr..

Comment: @GajaMounikaGaja : Additionally it all depends on how good is your DB configuration is, Try to increase vertically if possible(Ram/disk size/IOPS rate) & do load testing via couple of trial runs, Basically to say this question is self answered with research & trying different methodologies. Alternatively you can think of `sharding` if you collection is too big & is also depends on how often you read the data, if you can provide answers then someone can give you a set of solutions..